# iOS App purchase doesn't work in production

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I posted this question to Apple Development forum, but got no answer. Maybe I can get help here.

I'm trying to make in-app purchase work in my app. This is first app I developed and published for iOS, and I struggle to make in-app purchasing work. Here is timeline.

January 21 - I successfully published app to App Store on Sunday, January 21. The app is "Tennis Umpire App", written in Xamarin. I used component https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin so support purchasing. There is Android version with the same code where in-app purchasing works. This is just port to iOS.

January 22 - Discovered that In-App purchase doesn't work. No popup for the user, in the logs I see just "General Error". Tried on different devices, different accounts (on my friends phones). Then I realized that my contract for paid apps wasn't finished in iTunes connect, so I finished the contract. Tried again and it didn't help.

**Created new sandbox user to try in development version of the app, and it worked!**

January 23 - I found another post that it may take 24-48 hours to get things through, so I waited. Checked it from time to time - didn't work. In monitoring tools I can see that other people tried with same error.

January 25 - at this point 48 hours passed since I completed the contract. But it still doesn't work.

Any ideas in how to troubleshoot it further are appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you submitted your In-App purchase products for review? http://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev1986a0e5c

Comment: I submitted my app for review together with In-App purchase, and it all was approved. It is marked as Approved and Cleared for Sale. From approval letter:

The following app has been approved and the app status has changed to Ready For Sale:
App Name: Tennis Umpire App  
...
The following In-App Purchases are also approved:
• In-App Purchase Reference Name: Tennis Umpire Plus 
In-App Purchase Product ID: TennisUmpirePlus 
• In-App Purchase Reference Name: Tennis Umpire Plus 
In-App Purchase Product ID: TennisUmpirePlus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks what helped me is resetting "Clear for sale
 flag. I cleared check box, saved, and then marked it as "Clear for sale" and save again.